# Why am I getting a thread instead of my parameters?

Tags: lua, coroutine

I am using lua 5.3 from my C/C++ game to allow certain parts of its behavior to be scripted.

From the C++ program, every frame I call the lua function `main` in the following manner:

```
lua_getfield(VMState, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "main");
int result = lua_pcall(VMState, 0, 0, 0);
```

I expect the script to define a function called `main`, which does a bunch of stuff. For example, I can have a script that does something like this:

```
local f = function()
    draw_something({visible = true, x = 0, y = 0})
end

main = function()
    f()
end
```

`draw_something()` is a callback to the C code, which does something interesting with the parameters passed:

```
lua_getfield(VMState, 1, "visible");
bool visible = (bool)lua_toboolean(VMState, 2); lua_pop(VMState, 1);
if (!visible)
    return;
// Do some other stuff
```

Of interest, is that by the time this callback is called, the anonymous table I passed as a parameter to `do_something` in the lua side, is now at stack position 1, so I can call `lua_getfield()` from the C side, to access the `"visible"` field, and do something with it.

This works pretty well, and I've done lots of stuff like this for years.

Now, I want to convert the lua call to `f` to a coroutine, so I do something like this from the lua side:

```
local f = function()
    draw_something({visible = true, x = 0, y = 0})
end

local g = coroutine.create(function()
    while true do
        f()
        coroutine.yield()
    end
end

main = function()
    coroutine.resume(g)
end
```

The result should be the same. However, it now turns out that by moving the call to `draw_something()` inside a coroutine, the parameter I had passed to the function, which should have been a table, is now a thread? (`lua_istable()` returns 0, while `lua_isthread()` returns 1).

Interestingly, it doesn't matter how many parameters I pass to my function: 0, 1, 4, 50, from inside the callback I'm only getting one parameter, and it is a thread.

For some reason, this is happening with some functions that I exported, but not all. I can't see any difference in the way I'm exporting the different functions though.

Is there any reason why lua would switch my parameters to a thread?

Comment: why you write C++/C ? there is not C++/C line of code here , next time , write only LUA

Comment: @SkillerDz: The first and third blocks of code are in C/C++, and the unusual behavior is happening in the C/C++ side.

Comment: Did you build LuaJIT with option `-DLUA_USE_APICHECK`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: I was not aware of that flag. I am using msvcbuild.bat, So I added /DLUA_USE_APICHECK to LJCOMPILE, and rebuilt the game. I'm not getting any assertions or console ouptut. I changed this to /DLUA_USE_ASSERT, and nothing either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

It turns out that the `lua_State` that is passed to you on a `lua_CFunction` is not guaranteed to be the same to the one you first got on `lua_newstate()`

I suppose that each coroutine might get its own separate `lua_State`. If you always do stuff on the `lua_State` you got on `lua_newstate()`, you might have problems with coroutines, so you have to ensure you always use the `lua_State` you got passed on your `lua_CFunction`.

Comment: This is correct. Each coroutine gets created with its own stack, so in order for the API functions to work properly, a new `lua_State` is created, linking to the main state. A proper `lua_CFunction` implementation (one you pass to the Lua state) should use the Lua pointer passed in the parameters.